# Does a database systems latest driver support all previous versions?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I trying to develop a program, which as a part of it functionality, needs to connect to a selected database(either Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL etc). I am using java for the program. Is it okay for me to use the latest jar file for each database? Will this latest driver support connectivity to all the previous versions of the database. For example if I use sqljdbc4.jar for SQL Server, will it support even older SQL Servers like SQL Server 2000. Or do i need to include all the driver jar files for support and modify code based on version?

Comment: Without actually knowing it, I would suppose that this depends on the database / driver.

Comment: Depends. It may or might not. It is completely on the vendor implementation. You can read that it its manual.

Answer (score 1):

The database driver used within your code should match the version of the database you are using.  Why would you want to use a newer release of a driver when your not using the database it corresponds with?

With that being said many database drivers are backwards compatible to a certain point.  For example, the Oracle 11g Drivers state:

> The JDBC drivers are certified to work with the currently supported
>   versions of Oracle Database. For example, the JDBC Thin drivers in
>   Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1) are certified to work with the
>   10.2.x, 10.1.x, 9.2.x, and 9.0.1.x Oracle Database releases. However, they are not certified to work with older, unsupported database
>   releases, such as 8.0.x and 7.x.

You should investigate your target driver to determine its compatibility with the database your using.

Comment: Driver versions are not necessarily directly tied to the database version; and newer versions of a driver can also fix bugs/improve performance against an older database.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Agreed, I wasn't really considering minor version, more so the major version, ie 10g vs 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Most of jDBC drivers are backward compatible. When database are added new features, jDBC driver changes to support new features but will remain compatible for older version.